# How to add strings with each other during a loop?

Tags: python, string, loops

For my programming class, I need to a create a program that takes in a string and two letters as an argument. Whenever the first letter appears in the string, it is replaced with the second letter. I can do this by making the final string into a list. However, our professor has stated that he wants it to be a string, not a list. The code shown below is what I used to make the program work if the final result was to appear in a list.

```
def str_translate_101(string, x, y):
    new_list = []
    for i in string:
        if i == x:
            new_list.append(y)
        if i != x:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list
```

I tried to make one where it would output a string, but it would only return the first letter and the program would stop (which I'm assuming happens because of the "return")

```
def str_translate_101(string, old, new):
    for i in string:
        if i == old:
            return new
        else:
            return i
```

I then tried using the print function, but that didn't help either, as nothing was outputted when I ran the function.

```
def str_translate_101(string, old, new):
    for i in string:
        if i == old:
            print(new)
        else:
            print(i)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
An example of how the result should work when it works is like this:

str_translate_101('abcdcba', 'a', 'x') ---> 'xbcdcbx'

Comment: To append a letter (say "a") to a string (say `result`) you can write `result += "a"`. This isn't efficient but works.

Comment: The built-in `string.replace()` does it trivially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `join` to merge a list into a string:

```
def str_translate_101(string, x, y):
    new_list = []
    for i in string:
        if i == x:
            new_list.append(y)
        else:
            new_list.append(i)
    return ''.join(new_list)
```

or use the one-liner

```
str_tranlsate_101 = str.replace
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be, instead of storing the character in a list you can simply declare an empty string and in the 'if' block append the character to the string using the augmented '+=' operator. E.g.
    if i == x:
        concat_str += y

As for the return, basically, it will break out of the for loop and return to where the function was called from. This is because it only has 1 objective, which once achieved it will not bother to process any further code and simply go back to where the function was called from.